# Operation of complement and interior to open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $I$ is an open set in $X$. Let $E$ be its exterior, i.e. $E=\text{Ext}(I)=(X-I)^o$.

I assume that equality $\text{Ext(E)}=I$ holds but I cannot prove it.

It is the same as to prove that $I=I^{coco}$, where $*^c$ - operation of complement and $*^o$ - operation of interior.

I was able to show that $I^{coco}\subseteq I$ holds and it is quite trivial.

But how to prove the converse?

Would be grateful for help!

Comment: Do you mean *exterior* in the first line?

Comment: Ohh, thanks! Yes i meant exterior! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\text{Ext}(S) = \overline{S}^c$. Consider the open set 
$$
U =\ ]-\infty, 0[ \ \cup\  ]1,2[\ \cup\ ]2,3[\ \cup\ ]4, + \infty[
$$
Then 
\begin{align}
\overline{U} &=\ ]-\infty, 0] \ \cup\  [1,3]\ \cup\ [4, + \infty[ \\
\text{Ext}(U) = \overline{U}^c &=\ ]0,1[\ \cup\ ]3,4[ \\
\overline{\text{Ext}(U)} &=\ [0,1]\ \cup\ [3,4]  \\
\text{Ext}(\text{Ext}(U)) = \overline{\text{Ext}(U)}^c &=\ ]-\infty, 0[ \ \cup\  ]1,3[\ \cup\ ]4, + \infty[ 
\end{align}
Thus $\text{Ext}(\text{Ext}(U)) \not= U$.