# Help Proving this equalities related to topology in metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology

Let ($\mathit{M}$,d) be a metric space and $\Omega$ $\subseteq$ $\mathit{M}$, proof:

1. Int(Int($\Omega$)=Int($\Omega$)
2. Int(Ext($\Omega$))=Ext($\Omega$)
3. Ext(Int($\Omega$))=Ext($\Omega$)
4. Ext(Ext($\Omega$)=Int($\Omega$)

Ok folks, 1-2 are very easy considering the definition of interior of a set, and the fact that Ext($\Omega$)=Int($\Omega^c$) $\Rightarrow$
 Ext($\Omega$)=Int($\Omega^c$)=  Int(Int($\Omega^c$))=Int(Ext($\Omega$)  due to (1).

You may realice that (3) $\Rightarrow$ (4) or (4) $\Rightarrow$ (3) by the same treatment, but I'm stuck trying any of those.

Example: 
(4)

$\supseteq$)

We know that Ext($\Omega$) $\subseteq$ $\Omega^c$ $\Rightarrow$ Ext(Ext($\Omega$)) $\supseteq$ Ext($\Omega^c$) = (Int($\Omega$), because $\forall$ A,B $\subseteq$ M, A $\subseteq$ B $\Rightarrow$ Ext(A)  $\supseteq$ Ext(B).

$\subseteq$)

Let x $\in$ Ext(Ext($\Omega$)) $\Rightarrow$ $\exists$ $V_{r_{x}}^{d}(x)$ $\subseteq$ $(Ext(\Omega))^c$=$Int(\Omega) \cup \partial(\Omega)$
(that's because {$Int(\Omega),Ext(\Omega),\partial(\Omega)$} from a partition of $\mathit{M}$ ) $\Rightarrow$ $\forall$ y $\in$ $V_{r_{x}}^{d}(x)$,  y $\in$ $Int(\Omega) \cup \partial(\Omega)$. Since $Int(\Omega) \cap \partial(\Omega) = \emptyset \Rightarrow$ All points in that neiborghood are interior points of $\Omega$ or all are frontier points of $\Omega$.  In the first case we have in particular, that x $\in$ $Int(\Omega)$, wich means the contention holds true.
Supose now that x $\in$ $\partial(\Omega)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall$ $V_{r}^{d}(x)$, $V_{r}^{d}(x) \cap \Omega \not= \emptyset$ $\land$  $V_{r}^{d}(x) \cap \Omega^c \not= \emptyset$. In particular,  $V_{r_{x}}^{d}(x) \cap \Omega \not= \emptyset  \land V_{r_{x}}^{d}(x) \cap \Omega^c \not= \emptyset  $. I want to affirm that there's a interior point of $\Omega$ trapped in that neighborhood, say, $y$. That would imply that $\partial(\Omega) \cap Int(\Omega) \not=\emptyset $!! 
But I can't find a way.

I'm wondering if the proof is only true if $\Omega$ is an open set and not in general since if $\Omega$ is open $\Rightarrow Int(\partial(\Omega))=\emptyset$ (wich simplifies all).
The proof of (3) is essentially the same, you arrive at what I'm trying to prove with (4).

Comment: See this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362398/operation-of-complement-and-interior-to-open-set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. int int S = ing S because int S is open and the interior of an open set is the set itself.
2. int ext S = ext S because ext S is open.
3. ext int S = ext S is false.
   Let S = {2} $\cup$ (0,1).  int S = (0,1).
   ext int S = R - [0,1].  ext S = (R - [0,1]) - {2}.